# Flutter/Kotlin : Unresolved reference: FlutterPlugin

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

I'm working on a Flutter project and trying to implement AlarmManager natively with Kotlin, but I am encountering issues related to the Android Activity

Here are the two errors:

> MainActivity.kt: (5, 33): **Unresolved reference: FlutterPlugin**

> MainActivity.kt: (12, 35): **Type mismatch: inferred type is FlutterEngine but FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding was expected**

##### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.alarmapp

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(binding: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(binding)
        val plugin = AlarmScheduler()
        plugin.onAttachedToEngine(binding)
    }
}
```

##### app/build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10'
    implementation 'io.flutter:embedding-android:3.16.5
    implementation 'io.flutter:flutte:3.16.5'  
    implementation 'io.flutter.plugins:flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:2.0.0'
}
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.flutter:embedding-android:3.0.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/embedding-android/3.0.5/embedding-android-3.0.5.pom
      
     Required by:
         project :app
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.flutter:flutte:3.16.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/flutter/flutte/3.16.5/flutte-3.16.5.pom
        
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find io.flutter.plugins:flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:2.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/plugins/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/2.0.0/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.0.pom
       
     Required by:
         project :app
```